# glutinit arguments

Tags: opengl

I am beginner at openGL. In all simple examples main function has arguments and glutinit func uses those. But I don't understand why they are necessary. I write nothing in command arguments and the programs still works. What are they used for? Can you give an example?

```
glutInit(&argc, argv)
```

Comment: Link to documentation: [2.1 glutInit](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html)

Answer (score 13):

They're used so that GLUT can process command line arguments. It has a number of arguments that it always uses. If you don't want GLUT to process arguments, just pass something like this:

```
{
  int argc = 1;
  char *argv[1] = {(char*)"Something"};
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of it uses? When do I need those argument?

Comment: @paceman: On windows there is not so much use for it. But on other OSs you can use them to send the created windows to a different than the default display. (Standard Xlib `-display`) options. Also it may support the `-geometry` option to define the initial position and window size.

Comment: @peaceman: You never *need* them. But they could potentially be useful. If you don't need the arguments, then you can do what I suggested. They don't allow you to do anything you couldn't do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

glutInit is used to initialize the GLUT library. 
In C it is possible to accept command line arguments. Command-line arguments are given after the name of a program in command-line operating systems like DOS or Linux, and are passed in to the program from the operating system. To use command line arguments in your program, you must first understand the full declaration of the main function, which previously has accepted no arguments. In fact, main can actually accept two arguments: one argument is number of command line arguments, and the other argument is a full list of all of the command line arguments.

argcp: A pointer to the program's unmodified argc variable from main. Upon return, the value pointed to by argcp will be updated, because glutInit extracts any command line options intended for the GLUT library. 
argv: The program's unmodified argv variable from main. Like argcp, the data for argv will be updated because glutInit extracts any command line options understood by the GLUT library.

glutInit also processes command line options, but the specific options parse are window system dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario is when a **unix** `main()` accepts command line arguments, none of which we want to get "piped" by GLUT.

In this case we should declare and initialize "custom" GLUT initialization variables somewhere inside `main()`:

```
int foo = 1;
char * bar[1] = {" "};
glutInit(&foo, bar);
```